# Simple_html_dom Output data-attribute

Tags: php, html

my question is, I'm fetching an website content BUT i would like to fetch the tag name, ex:

```
<div data-target="12345">bla bla</div>
```

I would like to output the **12345** is it possible?

note: the **data-target** number is random and I would like to output it in an foreach

Comment: That's not the tag name it's the `data-target` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - how can I retrieve a div tag attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478330/php-how-can-i-retrieve-a-div-tag-attribute-value)

Comment: Fixed, ty btw!!