# How to remove HTML tag if it contains specific string

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, tags

```
    <tr>
        <td width="300" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="text-align: right;">
         <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sometext<br />
         </strong>
        </td>
        <td width="125" bgcolor="#009900" style="text-align: center;">
         <strong><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <span style="font-size: larger;">Pricetoreplace</span>
          </span>
         </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I need to remove whole `<tr>....</tr>` row, if it contain the "Pricetoreplace" text in it.
I've tried next:

```
$content = preg_replace('~(<tr.*[\'"]Pricetoreplace[\'"].*tr>)~', '', $content);
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Was there an error? Did it not delete anything?

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: It did not delete anything.

Comment: @gtktuf first off, you're going to replace everything from the first instance to the last `tr>` so your regex is not going to do what you expect (you use greedy quantifiers `.*` instead of lazy quantifiers `.*?`). Second, your `.` doesn't match new line characters, you should use `[\s\S]` instead or turn on the `s` flag to match newline characters with the `.` character. Again, though, you shouldn't even be using regex for this.

Comment: @gtktuf you really should be using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478330/php-how-can-i-retrieve-a-div-tag-attribute-value) question does.

Comment: @ctwheels. Thx. I understand that the use of regular expressions is not very suitable for this task, right?Based on your first reference

Comment: @gtktuf yes. It's usually bad practice to parse HTML or XML with regex. Regex should only be used for parsing HTML or XML if it's a known subset. In your case it doesn't appear to be so. I would recommend you use an HTML/XML parser and have it do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: If you *really* do want a regex for this, you can use something like `<tr(?:(?!<tr)[\s\S])*?>Pricetoreplace<[\s\S]*?tr>`, but I would **highly** recommend you don't go this direction.

Comment: @ctwheels Thx again. I'll try something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string)

Comment: @gtktuf you're welcome! I hope you find a proper solution. If you do, you can answer your own question. I would also suggest changing the title to something like `How to remove HTML tag if it contains specific string`. This would allow future users that might be struggling with the same issue to easily find a solution (yours) and might help generate traffic to this question (and hopefully give you upvotes). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) for more info about writing effective titles.

Comment: @gtktuf [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) post might help you. The second answer provides a method to get `tr` elements as well as extract the content, which should get you partway there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use an `xpath` query:

```
*//td[contains(., 'Pricetoreplace')]/parent::tr
```

Here, we look for a `td` which `text()` property contains `Pricetoreplace` and then look up the corresponding parent `tr`. The latter will be removed from the `DOM`.

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
    <tr><td class="some other class">some text here</td></tr>
   <tr>
        <td width="300" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="text-align: right;">
         <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sometext<br />
         </strong>
        </td>
        <td width="125" bgcolor="#009900" style="text-align: center;">
         <strong><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <span style="font-size: larger;">Pricetoreplace</span>
          </span>
         </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
DATA;

# set up the DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("*//td[contains(., 'Pricetoreplace')]/parent::tr") as $row) {
    $row->parentNode->removeChild($row);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

---

This yields

```
<tr><td class="some other class">some text here</td></tr>
```

Comment: That's the answer, but in my case i need to replace:

`$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);`

`$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` 
to solve some problems with encoding.
And there's no classes  like:
 `class="some other class"` 
 in the whole posts, wich i need to rebuild with this php script-that was the main problem. Ty for this method.

Comment: @gtktuf: Glad to help.